# Exit code from Windows Forms app

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How do i return a non-zero exit code from a Windows Forms application.

Application.Exit() is the preferred way to exit the application, but there is no exit code argument.

I know about Environment.Exit(), but that is not a nice way to close the application loop....

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[`Application.Exit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157894.aspx) just force the call to [`Application.Run`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157902.aspx) (That is typically in `program.cs`) to finish. so you could have :

```
Application.Run(new MyForm());
Environment.Exit(0);
```

and still inside your application call `Application.Exit` to close it.

Small sample

```
class Program
{
    static int exitCode = 0;

    public static void ExitApplication(int exitCode)
    {
        Program.exitCode = exitCode;
        Application.Exit();
    }

    public int Main()
    {
        Application.Run(new MainForm());
        return exitCode;
    }
}

class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        Program.ExitApplication(42);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Great example, very close to what i need.

Comment: make sure your exitcodes are positive integers, or else %ERRORLEVEL% on command prompt will return you 0 for negative codes. So in the sample, exitCode should be uint and ExitApplication should take uint as well.

Comment: Thank You, exactly what I needed.

Comment: **WRONG ANSWER.** `Environment.Exit()` does not terminate a Winforms application properly. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046019/winforms-application-exit-vs-environment-exit-vs-form-close

Answer (score 16):

If your `main` method returns a value you can return the exit code there.

Otherwise you can use [Environment.ExitCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exitcode.aspx) to set it. E.g. to set the would-be exit code when the main form is about to close:

```
private void FormMain_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    Environment.ExitCode = <exit code>;
}
```

Comment: +1 Great quick way to accomplish this. I have however a very big app, with quite a few possible exit codes and alot of different ways to exit. I will go with the example by VirtualBlackFox in my current application.

Answer (score -1):

Go to **event tab** in your form and in click place double click on it and then in code place write `Environment.Exit(0);`