# System.Environment.Exit(0) does not exit program

Tags: c#, system.exit

I have a console Application Program on Visual Studio 2013.
.NET 4.5
I want the program to quit after doing a Certain task. SO, I use
System.Environment.Exit(0);
but it does not exit. It only displays on the console: 
Press any key to continue.

How can i exit the Program?
Thanks in Advance.

Here iam checking if directory is empty, then exit the program, I also tried to put System.Environment.Exit(0); in the main function but it did nothing.

```
    if (Directory.GetFiles(@"Q:\").Length == 0)
    {
        System.Environment.Exit(0);
    }
```

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: Or just `return` if you are in the `Main` method.

Comment: You should use Application.Exit(). Environment.Exit would only kill the process. Check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046019/winforms-application-exit-vs-enviroment-exit-vs-form-close)

Comment: *It only displays on the console: Press any key to continue.* Looks like the standard behavior when you run a console app from the IDE. Does the same thing happen if you run the executable directly?

Comment: @kashi_rock No. This does not work for console applications.

Comment: Could it be that your program has additonal non-background threads running? These might keep the process running.

Comment: _Press any key to continue_ and it waits -- it sounds like a message generated by your IDE when your app terminates. Really, I remember it since at least the time I started with QBasic, but can't really remember if Borland products had the same behaviour. :)

Comment: Happens when you press Ctrl+F5 to start your program instead of F5.  Feature, not a bug, it lets you look at your program output before it closes the console window.  Without that it would be flash, bang, gone.  As would happen when you start your program from a shortcut on your desktop.

Comment: just return in the main method does not exit the console / Program

Comment: Exiting the console is different from exiting the program. *Any* C# program will exit when you leave the main method. As others have suggested, this may be a feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> Press any key to continue
> ```

Like a comment above said already, this sounds a lot like what your IDE (presumably Visual Studio) would print out once the process has terminated. On my machine, I get this message when I run a console application without attaching the debugger to it, e.g. by starting it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>. Once I press a key, the console window spawned by Visual Studio will close. This is expected behaviour.

Try running your program with the debugger attached, e.g. by pressing <kbd>F5</kbd>. Or start the program from a command prompt instead of starting it from your IDE. The message shouldn't be displayed then.

Note also that if you have a multi-threaded program, and there are non-background threads running, these can keep a process alive even though the main thread has terminated.

Answer (score 0):

The most graceful way to exit a console application is to return from the `Main` method.

Simply declare your main method as follows:

```
public static int Main(string[] args)
```

and you can use

```
return x;
```

to exit the application with the given return code.

Comment: Application.Exit gives me these two errors:

Error 2 Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement 
Error 1 'Application' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Windows.Forms.Application' and 'System.Windows.Application'

Comment: @Mike I didn't talk about `Application.Exit` - did you comment in the right place?

Comment: return x; does not exit the application

Comment: It doesn't exit the application or it doesn't exit the console window? Because returning from the main method *always* ends the application.

Comment: It does not close the application Console Window after finishing its task

Comment: Well, does the console window close when you start your program outside Visual Studio? As many others have mentioned, this is a feature when you use Ctrl+F5 in VS to run your program so you can see the output.

Comment: When i run the release version, the window closes, but when from the application itself, i press Ctrl and F5, the window does not close after the task of the program is finished

Comment: Well - did you *read* the other comments telling you that this is **normal, desired behavior** in Visual Studio?

Comment: So, this means that the application exits although the console does not close?

Comment: YES!! As you would have noticed had you run it outside Visual Studio or through F5 instead of Ctrl+F5.

Answer (score 0):

try `Application.Current.Shutdown()`

Comment: Error 2 'System.Windows.Forms.Application' does not contain a definition for 'Current' 

Error 1 'Application' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Windows.Forms.Application' and 'System.Windows.Application'

Comment: Why do you have both Windows forms and WPF assemblies referenced in a console application?