# Switching from form1 to form2

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have 2 forms

```
form1 = login,
form2 = main
```

I tried this to switch from `form1` to `form2`

```
(new Form2()).Show();
this.Hide();
```

And everything work just fine but when I close the program is still showing in the process manager/ doesn't stop debugging automatically, so how to fix that?

Comment: `Hide` does exactly that. it hides the form

Comment: This will probably help you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13046019/1220550

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add this line:

```
form2.Closed += (s, args) => Close();
```

So your code should be something like this:

```
Hide();
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
form2.Closed += (s, args) => Close();
form2.Show();
```

This will close `Form1` when you close `Form2`. If the user presses <kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> or `RightClick -> Close` on `Form2`, the `Form2` and the hidden `Form1` will be closed.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend a completely different and reliable method.

Login.cs

```
public partial class Login: Form
{
    public bool isLogin=false;//This should be public
    public Login()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }



    private void CheckUsernamePassword(string username,string password){
        if(username=="yourname" && password =="yourpass"){
           isLogin=true;
           this.close();
        }else{
           MessageBox.Show("Wrong username or password");
        }

     }
 }
```

Program.cs

```
//Remove this line
"Application.Run(new Form1());" replace

Login login = new Login();
Application.Run(login);
if(login.isLogin){// User logged
     Application.Run(new main());
}
```

This  code will work very successfully now.