C# .NET8 program doesn't exit when it should
I'm working on a program in C# .NET8.  It's designed to be able to run as either a windows forms app or to skip the form and run in an automated mode.  The program's purpose is to connect to an SFTP site, download any available files to the local machine, unzip them, and put them in a particular folder. Most of the time it will need to do this on its own, but occasionally I may need to run it manually in case it didn't previously run or new data was dropped to the SFTP site that I need to grab. As a matter of routine in my department, for most of our automated programs we write them with a windows forms interface for just this reason.
To invoke the automated mode, it's run in the windows task scheduler as a scheduled task and passes a command line argument ("AUTO") to indicate that the form isn't needed.  In the Program.cs file, if the command line arguments contain "AUTO" it passes that as a Boolean to the "Application.Run" line, i.e. Application.Run(new SomeProgramNameHere(automated)); (where "automated" is the Boolean value).
When I instantiate SomeProgramNameHere(), it looks like this:
public SomeProgramNameHere(bool Automatic = false)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    AutoMode = Automatic;
    Log = new Logging("SomeProgramNameHere");
    WriteToLog("STARTUP1.0", "SomeProgramNameHere", "This process Launched.");
    if (AutoMode)
    {
        MainProcess();
        WriteToLog("STARTUP1.1", "SomeProgramNameHere", "Exit from automated process.");
        Application.Exit();
        WriteToLog("STARTUP1.2", "SomeProgramNameHere", "Why didn't I exit?.");
    }
}

The actual work is done in the "MainProcess()" method.  When the program enters SomeProgramNameHere() it should do the regular InitializeComponent() step, then sets the class variable AutoMode (Boolean) based on the value passed in (this gets used elsewhere in the program as well), instantiates the logging process, writes a line to the log to say that it's launched, then, assuming it's in automated mode, goes into the MainProcess method.
Right after MainProcess() it originally had the Application.Exit() line.  When I built it and put it on the server to test it, the scheduled task ran, wrote to the log just fine, but didn't actually exit.  Looking in the Task Scheduler it showed it was still running, though it had hit the last step in the MainProcess() method.
I added the two additional logging lines seen above.  It hits them both.  So it's coming back from MainProcess(), hitting the logging line that says "STARTUP1.1", then hitting the line that says "STARTUP1.2".  If it's hitting that last line, it must be hitting Application.Exit(), but it doesn't exit.
If I add an on form load method and put the appliction exit in there (if (AutoMode) { Application.Exit(); } ), but I don't see why it has to hit the form load method at all.
I ran this by my supervisor and he was stumped as well.
I'm guessing that I'm making some idiotic fundamental error here, but I'm not sure what it would be.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.exit?view=windowsdesktop-8.0.  "This method does not necessarily force the application to exit. "

reading over that, yes, it says that it doesn't necessarily force the exit... but it specifically says that it's purpose is "
Informs all message pumps that they must terminate, and then closes all application windows after the messages have been processed."  If nothing else needs to be done, why isn't it exiting?
It appears that it DOES work if I put it into the form load event.  But I was trying to avoid the form from even having to open int he first place.

Perhaps you can use :
Environment.Exit(0);

to forcefully exit from whole environment.
here is a definition link of different way of exiting a program:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13046082/19465308

Thanks.  From what I was understanding in the discussion there, Application.Exit(); should be the better way to do it, as Environment.Exit(0); is more of a kill-switch to end the process.  Application.Exit() should execute any final code and then close out the application, right?  But it doesn't seem to do that.  I guess I'll go ahead and use Environment.Exit(0) to do it because I just need it to be done, but that feels wrong.
